# How to create a reusable block of statement for aws_iam_policy_document?

Tags: terraform0.12+

I have a few `aws_iam_policy_document` like these

**Policy1**

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy1" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:db:*
    ]
  }
  statement {
    actions = [
      "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:db:*s",
      "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:snapshot:*"

    ]
  }
}
```

**Policy2**

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy2" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
      "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:db:*",
      "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:db:*"
    ]
  }

}
```

And I have a few more policies which all have some variations.

Now I want to be able insert an identical block of `statement` to all of these policies.

It is not tested yet but the statement will look like this:

```
statement {

    action = [
        "ssm:GetParameter" 

    ]
    resources = [

"arn:aws:ssm:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:parameter/lambda/*"
    ]

}
```

What is the most efficient way to do it? I want to avoid copy and paste the same block of statement to  all policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the `source_json` keyword.

Here is an example:

First of all, define the common policy in new policy document

```
  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "common" {
    statement {

        action = [
            "ssm:GetParameter" 

        ]
        resources = [

    "arn:aws:ssm:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:parameter/lambda/*"
        ]

    }
  }
```

Then in the existing policy document, use  `source_json`

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy1" {
  source_json = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.common.json}"
  statement {
     ....
  }
}
```